# Elasticsearch percolate mapping error

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

I want to use percolate query in elasticsearch. But I couldn't setup mapping. I have received the following error. where is my fault?

```
    PUT /my-index
    {
        "mappings": {
            "doctype": {
                "properties": {
                    "message": {
                        "type": "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            "queries": {
                "properties": {
                    "query": {
                        "type": "percolator"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Error Message:

```
        {
           "error": {
              "root_cause": [
                 {
                    "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                    "reason": "No handler for type [percolator] declared on field [query]"
                 }
              ],
              "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
              "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [queries]: No handler for type [percolator] declared on field [query]",
              "caused_by": {
                 "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
                 "reason": "No handler for type [percolator] declared on field [query]"
              }
           },
           "status": 400
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: It's probably because you are using ES 2.x. The `percolator` type has been introduced in ES 5

Comment: Its true , my ES version 2.4.  Thank you Val , now I updating it

Comment: Cool, glad I could help.